# LINQ deletion - Can delete one way, can't using Single enumerable

Tags: sql-server, database, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

This works:

```
var i = (from x in db.Test
    where x.Id == 1
    select x).First();

db.Test.DeleteOnSubmit(i);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I get a cast error for this (int/string):

```
var i = db.Test.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
db.Test.DeleteOnSubmit(i);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I was also able to make an update using Single sucesssfully on the same table.  Any clues?

**Update**

Here's more of the error message:

Here's more:

[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.]
   System.Data.Linq.SingleKeyManager`2.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values, V& v) +134
   System.Data.Linq.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[] keyValues) +57
   System.Data.Linq.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues) +51
   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues) +113
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.GetOtherItem(MetaAssociation assoc, Object instance) +235
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.BuildEdgeMaps() +510
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +137
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +453
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges() +38

Comment: You mention that you get a cast error, but where does it come from? Does it give you any more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the data type of your id field?

I just ran the following code against a dummy database that has data in it where my key field is of type int:

```
using (var db = new dbDataContext())
{
    var x = db.items.Single(i => i.fld_key == 1);
    db.items.DeleteOnSubmit(x);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    var y = (from i in db.items
             where i.fld_key == 2
             select i).First();
    db.items.DeleteOnSubmit(y);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I had no problems with either, and checking the database, items 1 and 2 were both deleted successfully.

Are you attempting to delete an item that doesn't exist in the second code block - as you deleted it with the first.  This would mean that y is actually null and you're attempting to DeleteOnSubmit passing null which will give you an invalid cast as you can't cast null.

Try attempting to delete a *different* item in your second code block, I would imagine it would work in that case.

Change .Single to .SingleOrDefault and wrap your delete lines to check for null:

```
if(null != x)
{
    db.items.DeleteOnSubmit(x);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I would wager this will fix the problem you're seeing.

**Edit** Looking at the exception you've posted, I'm wondering if you changed the data type of your table to int after you generated your dbml.  Reload the table into your dbml and see if that fixes the issue.  Either that, or the issue is the other way around and you changed it to VarChar/NVarChar and haven't updated your dbml.

I would definitely take a look at your entities and make sure that the data types match those in your data table in your underlying database.

Comment: That helps.  I think there's something up with the entities.  There's an association.  This gives me something to check.

Comment: I would think `var i = db.Test.Single(x => x.Id == 1);` would throw an exception if it doesn't exist (as is normally the case)... but I guess LinqToSql might pick up that you're trying to grab the same item and give it to you instead of actually querying. This would seem pretty odd, but I'll be interested in seeing if this is the issue.

Comment: I have to plead incomplete information as the table was linked to another via fk.  I thought it was my LINQ syntax so I didn't mention it.  I got the error trying to delete from the fk table.  When I delete from the parent table, it works and the delete propagates down.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, glad you solved it in either case.  At least we have a question, a reasonable answer to the problem and a solution, even if they're not all coherently tied together.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the datatypes in your database lately? (Maybe those types currently differ from your generated classes)

Similarly, if you're using a stored procedure for deleting items, make sure the parameter types match up to your generated types.